# How to Find EmptyRow in Excel using VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Hope you all are doing fine.
I wrote a script in vb where excel will open and it will find an empty row in Column A & it will enter what i wrote in 1st Input box.
But there is some problem with the code. 
I don't know how to find an empty row. 
I need to execute in vbs file not in vba(i don't know the difference..sorry)
Thanks for help.. Awaiting response..

**Please find my code below:**

```
    Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ExcelObj : Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim x,y,objWorkbook,objWorksheet
x=InputBox("Enter the Expense Description..","Expense Description")
y=InputBox(x&"Enter the amount spent today..","Amount Spent")
ExcelObj.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mohammed Sajjad\Desktop\notss\SelfExpense.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Call TransInfo
Dim unusedRow
unusedRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
REM Dim emptyRow
REM emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
REM 'Transfer information
REM Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value
Sub TransInfo()
    With ExcelObj
    .Application.visible = True
    '.Workbooks.Add
    .Cells(1,1).Value="EXPENSE DESCRIPTION"
    .Cells(unusedRow,2).Value=x
    .Cells(2,1).Value="SPENT AMOUNT"
    .Cells(2,2).Value=y
    .Cells()
    End With
    '.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Mohammed Sajjad\Desktop\notss\SelfExpense.xlsx"
    objWorkbook.Save()
    ExcelObj.Quit
End Sub
MsgBox("Transfer Complete")
```

Comment: What is wrong with the way you are finding `unusedRow` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested .vbs

```
Option Explicit

Dim fn, x, y, xl, wb, itm, ws, unusedRow

fn = "C:\test.xlsx"

x = InputBox("Enter the Expense Description", "Expense Description")
If Len(x) > 0 Then          'if x is empty (length of 0) the user canceled
    y = InputBox("Amount spent on " & x & " today", "Amount Spent on " & x)
    If Len(y) > 0 Then      'if y is empty (length of 0) the user canceled
        On Error Resume Next    'we'll get an error if Excel is not open
        Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   'find Excel instance
        If Err Then         'if error - there were no Excel instances open
            Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  'create a new objecr
        Else                'we found an instance of Excel already open
            For Each itm In xl.Workbooks    'for each file already open in Excel
                If itm.Name = fn Then       'if file name is our file name
                    Set wb = itm            'set a reference to it
                    Exit For                'exit the loop
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fn) 'if file was not open
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)           'set a reference to 1st sheet in our file
        unusedRow = ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'get first empty row

        With ws
             .Cells(unusedRow, 1).Value = "EXPENSE DESCRIPTION" 'set cell A5
             .Cells(unusedRow, 2).Value = x                     'set cell B5
             .Cells(unusedRow + 1, 1).Value = "SPENT AMOUNT"    'set cell A6
             .Cells(unusedRow + 1, 2).Value = y                 'set cell B6
        End With
        wb.Save 'save file
        xl.Quit 'close Excel
        MsgBox "Transfer Complete"
    End If
End If
```

---

.

UsedRange and how to determine Last Row and Last Column

.

[image: UsedRange]

Comment: Thanks buddy for the awesome code. It works like a charm. Can u please explain me your code. Actually, i am very new to vbs. Like.. `code` For Each itm In xl.Workbooks
                If itm.Name = fn Then
                    Set wb = itm
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fn)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        unusedRow = ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count `code` .. Please explain this part.. Thanks

Comment: I added comments to explain what the code does . Please mark the answer that works for you as accepted, as a reference for other people, and feel free to upvote all answers you found helpfull

Comment: Thanks paul for the explanation. I want to close this question as Answered. How do i do that? (Sorry i am new to stackoverflow)

Comment: The question has an accepted answer - thanks for updating it, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unusedRow = 1 + objWorksheet.UsedRange.Row + objWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: UsedRange does not necessarily start on the first row.  You need UsedRange.Row + UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Thanks friends for the help. :) I will try now and will let u know the result.